# how to pass params as json arrays in postman having key and value pair

Tags: json, postman

I am not able to pass json array in postman with key and value pair.
when using like this working

```
[
   {
     "serviceTypeId": 40,
     "serviceName": "standard Cut2",
     "active": true,
    },
    {
     "serviceTypeId": 44,
     "serviceName": "Special Cut1",
     "active": true,
    },
    {
     "serviceTypeId": 46,
     "serviceName": "Feather xxxy",
     "active": true,
    }
]
```

but when i add a key its not(i.e like below)

```
{"serviceType": [
        {
            "serviceTypeId": 40,
            "serviceName": "standard Cut2",
            "active": true,
        },
        {
            "serviceTypeId": 44,
            "serviceName": "Special Cut1",
            "active": true,
        },
        {
            "serviceTypeId": 46,
            "serviceName": "Feather xxxy",
            "active": true,
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Json is not correctly formatted, there is an extra comma after active attribute. Remove it. It should be :

```
[  
   {  
      "serviceTypeId":40,
      "serviceName":"standard Cut2",
      "active":true
   },
   {  
      "serviceTypeId":44,
      "serviceName":"Special Cut1",
      "active":true
   },
   {  
      "serviceTypeId":46,
      "serviceName":"Feather xxxy",
      "active":true
   }
]
```

Try this in array :

```
{  
   "serviceType":[  
      {  
         "serviceTypeId":40,
         "serviceName":"standard Cut2",
         "active":true
      },
      {  
         "serviceTypeId":44,
         "serviceName":"Special Cut1",
         "active":true
      },
      {  
         "serviceTypeId":46,
         "serviceName":"Feather xxxy",
         "active":true
      }
   ]
}
```

When your not sure about your JSON you can use tools on the internet like this : https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ .

You will be able to see quickly if your json is correct.